# Multiple instances of nodelets

Tags: ros, nodelet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my application I am planning to convert a node to a nodelet. Before going ahead with my implementation I want to clarify some doubts.

1. In the application I am currently running multiple instances of a node. If I port that node to nodelet, is it possible to    have multiple nodelet instances as in nodes?
2. If that provision was not there what was the best way to implement zero copy mechanism of nodelts.

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257597/multiple-instances-of-nodelets/) by [mkreddy477](https://answers.ros.org/users/29390/mkreddy477/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2017-03-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> is it possible to have multiple nodelet instances as in nodes

yes.

As long as you provide a different name for each instance (same as with nodes).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mkreddy477](https://answers.ros.org/users/29390/mkreddy477/) on 2017-03-23**:
Thanks for the info